# Einstein-Rosen bridge through multiverse?

Tags: wormholes, multiverse

The Einstein-Rosen bridge describes a short cut between two point by "connecting" the two destinations in a folded 2-dimensional representation of the three dimensional universe, but if the universe is actually a multiverse wouldn't the short cut have to "tunnel" through multiple universes for this to even be possible and connect to another point within the same universe? If this is true then wouldn't this "tunnel" also have to go through an infinite amount of universes? Or would this "tunnel actually be a three dimensional "tunnel" existing wihin a four dimensional space?

Comment: To reopen this question (v2) consider to include reference to pertinent definition of multiverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Einstein-Rosen bridge is a solution to the General Relativity equations (GR) in one spacetime. You don't need to invoke multiverses for it. The BH tunnel open at one spacetime area, and goes to another, it does not need anything in between. No need to interpret going out of the universe, it just means that the topology of the spacetime includes the wormhole (or many). Still, some people interpret it as a separate universe, but it is interpretation. See a description of wormholes and a number of issues at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole

Having said that, it's not the end of the story. Some of the following is also covered in the wiki reference.

1) the Einstein-Rosen bridge is unstable, and the tunnel closes rapidly, too rapid to transverse it. That was found by Wheeler. Wheeler assumed that the mass always had to be positive, a so called positive energy condition.

Note also that you have to treat wormholes in the full 4 dimensional spacetime. Not just 3D space, but that and time. If you look in less or more dimensions you can get different answers, but you still have to treat it in a Lorentzian metric (1 time dimension, multiple space dimensions. I think there's also solutions with 2 time dimensions, but not clear what that woul mean in our universe)

There is also BHs in the Einstein-Cartan theory, with spin interactions allowing the tunnel to stay open.

2) GR does not absolutely require positive energy or mass. The same is true in quantum field theory (QFT). More on QFT below. But even in GR if you allow negative mass, often part of what people mean when they say exotic particles, then the tunnel stabilizes and it becomes possible. In that case you go from one spacetime point to other, maybe very far or in the past or future. You come out (if somehow you survive, but consider just a particle going through) coming out of the WHITE Hole on the other side.

3) GR with some quantum matter can also cause something similar, such as if you have a scalar quantum field in the internal region. Also see the wiki article. This so called Ellins wormhole is transversable, meaning you can go and come come back. In the Einstein-Rosen solution it's only one way. There is discussion and papers on whether transversable BHs can bring  you back to the past, in the same spatial region you started. Some argue that they can't as you could then cause the chronology paradox (kill your father before you were born), but there's no conclusion in physics at this point.

4) Some physicists do claim that when you transverse you go to another universe, not the same one, but a parallel one, as in the movie Interstellar. It's conjecture, nobody knows, but it is not prohibited by the equations or theory.

Comment: Wouldn't bending or manipulating our space-time Affect any space-time near our universe? even if the wormhole can exist Without a multiverse, if we were to exist within a multiverse I just think a worm hole would influence the other universes around ours, or any event really or change in the topology.

Comment: Frankly, I don't think there is any accepted theory that says anything about how different universes Ina multiverse would affect each other. I do think that String Theory tends to lead to the multiverses being independent of each other except for gravity (but I don't remember for sure), so it would then not be inconceivable that wormholes could connect them. But it is a mostly speculative discussion. Wormholes are speculative enough, and add multiverses which are also purely speculative and it's hard to be convinced of anything.